# How to set IBM Websphere 8 to serve web applications on different ports?

Tags: port, web-applications, websphere

I need to deploy two applications as WAR files on Websphere.
Both of them will require only HTTPS access.

Is it possible to run these two web applications on separate ports on same Websphere instance?

For example, will it be possible to access two applications like this:

```
https://192.101.1.101:7070/WebApplication1/
```

and

```
https://192.101.1.101:7080/WebApplication2/
```

(Same IP, same protocol(https), different ports)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible! However it depends on the WebSphere Version you are using.
With WebSphere Application Server Network Deployment simply create a new JVM (aka "WebSphere Application Server") by navigation to "Servers > Server Types > WebSphere application servers > New ..."
Each dedicated JVM has its own https ports (Servers > Server Types > WebSphere application servers >  Ports). After creating the new jvm just deploy your two apps in the different jvms.

If you have the WebSphere Base Version, creating new JVMs is not supported in the GUI. You need to use wsadmin-scripting. [This blog post describes how to create a new server with wsadmin](http://www.devops-insight.com/2008/05/add-additional-application-to-was-61.html).

As an alternative you could create a new profile (complete configuration set) on the same host. Use the manageprofile tool for that. [This blog post explains how to create a new Websphere profile](http://www.devops-insight.com/2014/09/how-to-create-new-websphere-profile.html)

Another solution is to add a transport chain and a port to the jvm. For that go to "Servers > Server Types > WebSphere application servers > server1 > Web container transport chains > New..." and give your chain a name and select "WebContainer-secure". Click next. Type in your wished secondary https port and click next and finish.
Save the configuration and restart your websphere.

However this secondary https port can be used by both applications.

Comment: I'll check whether we have a ND license. As of now I seem to be working with standalone server. Creating new JVM in standalone server seems like a hack... Looks like its not allowed for standalone license? Will I get support if I use that configuration?

Comment: to be honest - i don't know if IBM supports it. As an alternative you could create a complete profile instead of a JVM. Profiles are complete configuration sets. If you create a new profile on the same machine you do not need additional PVUs - and it is fully supported by IBM. I edited my answer regarding that. To create a new profile use the manageprofile-tool:
http://www.devops-insight.com/2014/09/how-to-create-new-websphere-profile.html